# GKE master node

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE, when we create nodes, there will be a master node and many worker nodes will be created.
I have a doubt whether master node is the one among which we created(replicas mentioned) or GKE creates master node separately.
And What is the topology(eg.,mesh,star) in which gke cluster is formed ?

Comment: you can't see the master. 
You can check out the nodes your using by looking at the node pools, or just query the backing compute instances (gcloud compute instances list)

Comment: No, the nodes that we see is Actually worker Nodes. Master Nodes in GKE is hidden and Google Manages on your behalf. Regarding the No of master nodes, it is not known as master is in HA mode and is given to us as an API endpoint which is whole point of managed cluster.

Answer (score 19):

In GKE, if you create a standard cluster you will have API access to one master node, if you create a regional cluster you will have three master nodes but you will access them in One endpoint (one in each zone of the region).

GKE is a managed Kubernetes cluster, The master node is not visible among your service node you can only access it through the API only.

The default GKE configuration (topology) see the below screen

[image]

Here is some documentation regarding [Private cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdh0v.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GKE deploys a master node in a separate project managed by GCP itself. The nodes visible in your projects are only worker nodes.

If you create zonal cluster then you will have one master node, and if you create regional then there will be total 3 master nodes.