# Why I can not get master node information in full-managed kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

everyone.

Please teach me why `kubectl get nodes` command does not return master node information in full-managed kubernetes cluster.

I have a kubernetes cluster in GKE. When I type `kubectl get nodes`command, I get below information.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                      STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-istio-test-01-pool-01-030fc539-c6xd   Ready    <none>   3m13s   v1.13.11-gke.14
gke-istio-test-01-pool-01-030fc539-d74k   Ready    <none>   3m18s   v1.13.11-gke.14
gke-istio-test-01-pool-01-030fc539-j685   Ready    <none>   3m18s   v1.13.11-gke.14
$
```

Off course, I can get worker nodes information. This information is same with GKE web console.
By the way, I have another kubernetes cluster which is constructed with three raspberry pi and kubeadm. When I type `kubectl get nodes` command to this cluster, I get below result.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
master   Ready    master   262d   v1.14.1
node01   Ready    <none>   140d   v1.14.1
node02   Ready    <none>   140d   v1.14.1
$
```

This result includes master node information.

I'm curious why I cannot get the master node information in full-managed kubernetes cluster. 
I understand that the advantage of a full-managed service is that we don't have to manage about the management layer. I want to know how to create a kubernetes cluster which the master node information is not displayed.
I tried to create a cluster with "the hard way", but couldn't find any information that could be a hint.

At the least, I'm just learning English now. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GKE master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434561/gke-master-node)

Comment: Thank you for your information. It's good information, but I want to know that why I cannot get master node information using `kubectl get node` command. In other word, I want to know what settings cause this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question!

The key is `kubelet` component of the Kubernetes.
Managed Kubernetes versions run Control Plane components on masters, but they don't run `kubelet`. You can easily achieve the same on your DIY cluster.

> The kubelet is the primary “node agent” that runs on each node. It can **register** the node with the apiserver using one of: the hostname; a flag to override the hostname; or specific logic for a cloud provider.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

> When the kubelet flag --register-node is true (the default), the kubelet will attempt to **register** itself with the API server. This is the preferred pattern, used by most distros.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#self-registration-of-nodes

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer. That is exactly what I was looking for.
"register-node" flag is the key. I understand it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that managed Kubernetes don't run `kubelet` at all on their masters. Main function of `kubelet` is to run pods. So if master is not supposed to run pods, then there's no reason to run `kubelet` there.

Answer (score 4):

Because there are no nodes with that role. The control plane for GKE is hosted within their own magic system, not on your own nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that GKE control plane is hosted on GCP's magic system. I think, however, there are any master node in GCP's magic system area. I want to know what settings hide them.

Comment: Nothing is hidden because there is no "master node". While you have a control plane (kube-apiserver, etc) that your cluster connects to, it is not running on a node that is part of your cluster.